# "docker run -i busybox sh" fails with \r characters or ": not found" on Windows

Tags: docker

I understood the differences in terms of --i and --t flag, However - when i ran the two following commands, they behave differently in returning the results

```
$ docker run -it busybox sh                                                        
Unable to find image 'busybox:latest' locally                                      
latest: Pulling from library/busybox                                               
bdbbaa22dec6: Pull complete                                                        
Digest: sha256:6915be4043561d64e0ab0f8f098dc2ac48e077fe23f488ac24b665166898115a    
Status: Downloaded newer image for busybox:latest                                  
/ # ls                                                                             
bin   dev   etc   home  proc  root  sys   tmp   usr   var                          
/ #
```

The above works. Now , i removed --t flag ,where i am expecting "ls" should return results though tty is not attached.

```
$ docker run -i busybox sh  
ls                          
: not found
```

What could be the reason - ls is not available , sounds weird ?

Edit 1: few more observations -

```
$ docker run -i ubuntu                                   
ls                                                       
/bin/bash: line 1: $'ls\r': command not found            
pwd                                                      
/bin/bash: line 2: $'pwd\r': command not found           
exit                                                     
/bin/bash: line 3: $'exit\r': command not found
```

one more,

```
$ docker run -i ubuntu sh   
ls                          
: not found                 
exit                        
: not found
```

Comment: `$'ls\r'` not existing is normal. The command name is just `ls`; it's not supposed to have a carriage return after it.

Comment: Also, when a carriage return is printed, it sends the cursor back to the beginning of the line. Hence, your error message deleting everything before that character.

Comment: ...now, *how* you're feeding carriage returns to docker's stdin when TTY emulation is not enabled is a different question. If I had to guess -- are you using a Windows-native terminal? (On Windows, newlines are two-character CRLF sequences, whereas on UNIX they're only one character, a LF alone).

Comment: @Charles, you are right. I just figured it out. thanks. BTW, how we can fix this if we were to run the command from windows

Comment: I don't do Windows, so someone else will need to answer that. Hopefully, with the more explicit title, someone with the relevant expertise will find the question and be able to chime in.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem with line endings. I am running commands from windows . Anyways, I switched to docker-machine , things are working now .

please see here - https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1891

Not sure how to fix this while running in windows

```
 $ docker-machine ssh                                          
   ( '>')                                                     
  /) TC (\   Core is distributed with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. 
 (/-_--_-\)           www.tinycorelinux.net                   

docker@default:~$ sudo su root                                
root@default:/home/docker# docker run -i busybox sh           
ls                                                            
bin                                                           
dev                                                           
etc                                                           
home                                                          
proc                                                          
root                                                          
sys                                                           
tmp                                                           
usr                                                           
var                                                           
exit
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I tried to tighten up the question title a little so that the answer gets found and read by people who need it.